# How to get the selected shipping rate?

Tags: magento2, shipping

I have a a module that makes a soap call to a service to retrieve live shipping quotes, and it returns a bunch of data, an import fee being one of those things it returns.

I have created a new **AbstractTotal class** called **ImportFee** and I need a way to set the amount of this fee to be the amount of the user's selected **shipping rate's** import fee. I have already stored the import fee on my shipping rates in an **extension_attribute**, I just do not know how I am supposed to obtain the object from the **AbstractTotal class**.

If some code is needed, please ask which code would be specific. I do not want to spam this with a bunch of code. The concept is the same.

I have an **extension_attribute** on my **shipping rate**, and I need to set an AbstractTotal class value to that **extension_attribute**. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Declare `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` in construct of your class.

Try following snippet:

```
protected $_cart;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $_cart
) {
    $this->_cart = $_cart;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Then you can do following:

```
$shippingAmount = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
```

Answer (score 4):

In Magento 2 YOu can use this Code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

$shipping_amount=$cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
```

Answer (score -1):

To get selected shipping rate from current quote please use below code:

```
quote = Mage::getModel("checkout/session")->getQuote();
$amount = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
```

Comment: I should have clarified I am on magento 2. I will update my question, and I am not looking for the shipping amount, I am looking for an attribute_extension i put on the shipping rate